# Identifying a four-pin IC labelled EL 8+7 G8025

Tags: components, identification, charger

I want to know the purpose of a component named "EL 8+7 G8025" which was found inside a Nokia charger.

[image: Blurry photo]

Comment: That is not exactly a sharp foto, but it shows that the component is across an isolation gap in the bord, which supports Sperho's idea that it could be an optocoupler (the 817 is a jellybean optocoupler).

Comment: A clearer photo is definitely required here.

Comment: Apologies for the photo quality. I have tried my level best to upload a clearer picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly an [EL817](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/breakout/Relay/EL817.pdf) optocoupler, but I'll reserve final judgement until I see the photo. If it's a semiconductor the only common 4-pin parts used in this sort of application are bridge rectifiers and opto-couplers. There are other 4-pin parts such as common-mode chokes, but they look different.

[image]

Bridge rectifiers look more like this:

[image: http://www.otenko.com/gallery3/var/albums/model-mods/dcc_tinkering/Dsc06225.jpg?m=1272972695]

Comment: Yeah,it is a EL 817 chip. I couldn't read it properly with naked eyes. It is an opto-coupler,then!  Thank you.

Comment: @user3347036 if this answered your question you should accept it an the answer.  The person posting the answer gets points for their effort.

Comment: Done..........!